# Converting flat Python Dictionary to List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary in the following format where I don't know the number of lines or items I'm going to receive:

```
{'line(0).item1':'a', 'line(0).item2':'34', 
 'line(1).item1':'sd', 'line(1).item2':'2', 'line(1).item3':'fg', 
 'line(2).item1':'f' ... }
```

What is the most pythonic way to parse this into a list of dictionaries in the following format:

```
[{'item1':'a', 'item2':'34'}, 
 {'item1':'sd', 'item2':'2', 'item3':'fg'}, 
 {'item1':'f',...}, ...]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
d = {'line(0).item1':'a' ...}

out = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k,v in d.items():
    n,val = re.findall(r'^line\((\d+)\)\.(\w+)$', k)[0]
    out[int(n)].append((val,v))

my_list = [dict(out[v]) for v in sorted(out)]
```

and the output will be the expected:

```
[{'item2': '34', 'item1': 'a'}, {'item2': '2', 'item3': 'fg', 'item1': 'sd'}, {'item1': 'f'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with an intermediate dictionary of dictionaries, since there is no way of knowing how many "lines" you'd have at the end and you can't insert a new element at the end of the list later.

It should be simple enough to iterate over every element in this `dict` and parse it into the line number and key. You could then easily transfer the new `dict` into the list you desired. A possible implementation could be:

```
intermediate_dict = {}
for entry in my_dict:
    line_string, key = entry
    line_number = int(line_string[line_string.index('(') + 1: line_string.index(')')])
    if line_number not in intermediate_dict:
        intermediate_dict[line_number] = {}
    intermediate_dict[line_number][key] = my_dict[entry]

new_list = []
for i in xrange(len(intermediate_dict)):
    new_list.append(intermediate_dict[i])
```

Comment: this will only work up to `line(9)`... Also, you should use `dict.setdefault` or `collections.defaultdict` to replace the `if`

Comment: @JBernardo Why would it only work until `line(9)`? I don't see any assumption of a single digit here...

Comment: sorry, I saw the `+1` but forgot the slicing.