# Convert dictionary lists to multi-dimensional list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I've been trying to convert the following:

```
data = {'title':['doc1','doc2','doc3'], 'name':['test','check'], 'id':['ddi5i'] }
```

to:

```
[{'title':'doc1', 'name': 'test', 'id': 'ddi5i'},
{'title':'doc2', 'name': 'test', 'id': 'ddi5i'},
{'title':'doc3', 'name': 'test', 'id': 'ddi5i'},
{'title':'doc1', 'name': 'check', 'id': 'ddi5i'},
{'title':'doc2', 'name': 'check', 'id': 'ddi5i'},
{'title':'doc3', 'name': 'check', 'id': 'ddi5i'}]
```

I've tried various options (list comprehensions, pandas and custom code) but nothing seems to work. For example, the following:

```
panda.DataFrame(data).to_dict('list')
```

throws an error because, since it tries to map the lists, all of them have to be of the same length. Besides, the output would only be uni-dimensional which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: This looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778465/converting-flat-python-dictionary-to-list-of-dictionaries

Comment: Take a look at `itertools`, seems like a combinatorics problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) may be what you're looking for here, and it can be applied to the values of your data to get appropriate value groupings for the new dicts.  Something like

```
list(dict(zip(data, ele)) for ele in product(*data.values()))
```

**Demo**

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(dict(zip(data, ele)) for ele in product(*data.values()))
[{'id': 'ddi5i', 'name': 'test', 'title': 'doc1'},
 {'id': 'ddi5i', 'name': 'test', 'title': 'doc2'},
 {'id': 'ddi5i', 'name': 'test', 'title': 'doc3'},
 {'id': 'ddi5i', 'name': 'check', 'title': 'doc1'},
 {'id': 'ddi5i', 'name': 'check', 'title': 'doc2'},
 {'id': 'ddi5i', 'name': 'check', 'title': 'doc3'}]
```

It is clear how this works once seeing

```
>>> list(product(*data.values()))
[('test', 'doc1', 'ddi5i'),
 ('test', 'doc2', 'ddi5i'),
 ('test', 'doc3', 'ddi5i'),
 ('check', 'doc1', 'ddi5i'),
 ('check', 'doc2', 'ddi5i'),
 ('check', 'doc3', 'ddi5i')]
```

and now it is just a matter of zipping back into a dict with the original keys.